# how do i use spark master on zeppelin cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have spark master and zeppelin docker container 
[image]

I want to use this master on zeppelin

[image]

is this right setting? or is there something else? 
and how to check my setting is right?

Comment: How is the cluster deployed? Is Spark deployed with YARN or standalone are you using doing the setup manually or are you using a platform like HDP or Cloudera? Without all this information it would be difficult to tell if this are setup correctly.

Comment: i'm not sure its yarn or standalone. https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark i clone this git. and docker compose up. then it create the master and worker spark .

Comment: You can set the `spark.master` property as `spark://spark-master:7077`

Comment: if I want to go to the webpasge screen for spark what address should I use?

Comment: It should be port 8080 as defined `ENV SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT 8080`

Comment: fa9871f90737        bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7   "/bin/bash /master.sh"   42 hours ago        Up 2 minutes               6066/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp   spark-master

02b0b199f330        nginx                                  "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 weeks ago         Exited (0) 40 hours ago

Comment: when i start spark ui it said "No spark application running"